# how does one get csharp-sqlite to throw exceptions for duplicates or foreign key constraint violations

Tags: sqlite

I am currently making use of csharp-sqlite. In the SQLite database I have some uniqueness and foreign key constraints. But when I write a "duplicate" to a table an exception is not raised and the only way I found to check for an exception is to use something like the following:

```
var error = sqliteCommand.GetLastError();
```

I was hoping to be able to do the following:

```
var sqlstring = "some insert sql";
var command = SqliteCommand(sqlstring);
command.Parameters.Add(... some parameter...);

using (var sqlConnection = new SqliteConnection(connectionString))
{
     try
     {
          command.ExecuteNonQuery();
     }
     catch (Exception ex)
     {
          do something with the exception
     }
     finally
     {
          sqlConnection.Close();
     }
}
```

The "catch" block is never hit, even though the

```
var error = sqliteCommand.GetLastError();
```

does return with a description of the error that I was expecting. Does anyone have an idea how to solve this, or what standard practice is using the csharp-sqlite library?

Comment: Did you enable foreign keys?

Comment: yes, foreign keys are enabled. "PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON;" But I also have a uniqueness constraint that is being violated in a test case and no exception is raised but the sqlitecommand.GetLastError() does return something like "column UserName is not unique".